# Meaning of "Mensa"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> Q: Did you go ahead with Mensa?
>
> A: I did, and then I quit. Too many bus drivers feeding their egos on the professors, and the professors marveling at how intelligent they're making bus drivers these days. The whole thing was a little sick.

I have got no idea what is its meaning?

Comment: because in this context two police are discussing I doubt whether its meaning is something different from High IQ society.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Mensa](https://www.mensa.org/)** is a high IQ society. From their website:

> Mensa, the high IQ society, provides a forum for intellectual exchange among its members. There are members in more than 100 countries around the world.